# Prevent multiple connections while file download in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is a PHP `function download()` that allows user to download the file. The decrypted file is created on server and provided to user using `readfile($file)` . But when **[Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)** downloads it using multiple connections, it makes multiple connections and that file is created multiple times on the server, one for each connection. What could be the best possible solution to create only one file for single user, even when there are multiple requests for download. And after download the should be deleted also.
Following is the sample code for download.

```
public function download($new_filename,$original_filename){
    $fp2=fopen($new_filename,'wb'); //create empty file name $new_filename
    fputs($fp2,base64_decode(file_get_contents($original_filename)));//decoding and writing to $fp2

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/".$ext);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($new_filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($new_filename);

    /***** removing temporary decoded file ****/
    if(file_exists($new_filename)) {
        chmod($new_filename,0777); //Change the file permissions if allowed read and write and execute
        unlink($new_filename); //remove the file
    }
    fclose($fp2);
}
```

Comment: "when Internet Download Manager downloads it, it makes multiple connection" if it use the same ip address you can match it with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and don't recreate your file.

Comment: Why are you storing the `base64` content of the file in the first place?

Comment: So how should I define a variable with scope limited for same client..

Comment: Normally you would use session variables to have a variable in the "client scope" if you will. But download managers might not send the same cookies as the browser, so that might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to accomplish what you want is something like this:

Generate unique download urls with a "ticket" that gives one time access to the file (eg. `dl.php?file=ABC123&ticket=1231292`), store this ticket in a database or some other structure when you generate it, so that you can invalidate it when the download begins.

In your download script you check if the ticketid is valid, if not you respond with a 403 HTTP status.
If it is valid then begin generating the file etc., invalidate the ticket and then start to send the file to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `base64_decode` and `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile` like:

```
public function download($new_filename,$original_filename) {

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: application/".$ext);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize(base64_decode(file_get_contents($original_filename))));

    echo base64_decode(file_get_contents($original_filename));

}
```

And you can add something to lock 1 connection by ip address using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: How can lock only one connection for ip address. There is no variable or datamember that retain values between calls to that function by same ip address. Or I have to take help of database for that?

Comment: You can set the ip address in a database like MySQL, or using NoSQL like memcache and set a key (http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php), or filecaching in codeigniter (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html#file). After downloading don't forget to remove the ip address.